# How did technicians individually hand-shim each Pentax/Konica 35mm slr lens mount?

Tags: film, optics, lens-mount, slr, konica

I just received a Konica Autoreflex T and I found out that the lens mount is individually hand shimmed.

How did the technicians determine if the lens mount is correctly parallel to the focal plane?

Comment: It sounds to me like sloppy manufacturing precision means they *had to* shim the mount! I can't imagine they designed their manufacturing process to *require* shimming the mount. But perhaps I simply lack imagination…